# How to do multiple point transclusion to parent in angular (example simpler than title)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implements a 'simple' tabs directive in angular. The only difference is that both the tab nav and the tab content can have html.

I want my code to look like that :

```
 <home-tabs>
        <home-tab>
            <home-tab-header>
                Some html in the first tab header
            </home-tab-header>
            <home-tab-content>
                Some html in the first tab content
            </home-tab-content>
        </home-tab>
        <home-tab>
            <home-tab-header>
                Some html in the second tab header
            </home-tab-header>
            <home-tab-content>
                Some html in the second tab content
            </home-tab-content>
        </home-tab>
</home-tabs>
```

which would generate the following html :

```
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="nav-el">Some html in the first tab header</div>
        <div class="nav-el">Some html in the secondtab header</div>
    </div>
    <div class="contents">
        <div class="content">Some html in the first tab content</div>
        <div class="content">Some html in the second tab content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which mean the home-tab directive must not inject it's element anywhere, but instead inject it's two subdirective in two differents places in the parent ( home-tabs ) directive element.

I know the tricks is probably in using the compile function of the home-tabs, or home-tab directive, but I'm not sure exactly what is the cleaner approach to do this. I can do this the hacky-jquery way, but I hope there is a more "angular" approach to this problem. Isn't it ?

Any thoughts ? Can someone help me there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, they have an open issue on that matter: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4350

However, AngularUI tab does almost what you want to do with this syntax:

```
<tabset>
  <tab>
    <tab-heading>
      <b>First</b> Tab
    </tab-heading>
    first content
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

Maybe you can use their component or have a look at their [implementation](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabs/tabs.js).

Comment: I looked at angular-ui but i missed the fact that they add this syntax as an option for their tabs. Thanks. As expected, the implementation seems overly complicated for what we're trying to accomplish, but I least i know there is no simpler solution. Accepting your answer at the solution.